# Option "abnt-year-extra-label" of package "abntcite" does not work

Tags: bibtex, citing

Just did as recommended by the `abntcite` package docs, and set 
`\usepackage[alf,abnt-year-extra-label=yes]{abntcite}`
in order to have references with same author and same year identified as `year + letter`, e.g.: citation `(Silva, 2011a)` and reference `Silva, A. M. <title> ... 2011a.`
However, it didn't work. Other people complained as well, but no solution til now.
Sugestions, please?

Comment: sigh.  a package on a "private" web site (rather than the archive) with documentation in a language i don't read.  are there many brazilian texies on tex/sx? (i've not noticed them) -- i assume you need such people to help with such a package.

Comment: Hi @Fausto, [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I tried your setting here and the output is as expected. I suspect there are other settings in your document that are clashing. Could you come up with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your issue? That way we might be able to track down the issue.

Comment: With no MWE, this is 'too localised'.